# Saving the plots and results as html

Tags: html, r

I would like to save the plots produced in R as HTML. I have used the following code

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(df, "test.html")
```

But, I could not save it, and I got the following message:

> Error in system.file (config, pakage=pakage) : 'package' must be of
>   length 1

Is it possible to save file as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

As J.D.Currie suggested, you must have an html widget, or in other words, `htmlwidget` class object (or any inherited class). You can get the class of your plot by `class(df)` to see whether they are htmlwidgets or not. In case your plots are not `htmlwidget`, you want to produce interactive graphs and export them as .html; there is a variety of packages for it, such as, `plotly`,`highcharter`,`dygraphs` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From the wording of the question, it doesn't read like you've created a widget object (you say 'plots' and then use 'df' as an argument), which would be done first. In the case of saveWidget(), you're passing at least a widget object and the file name you wish to create.

[Read the package documentation.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/htmlwidgets.pdf)

[Also look at the basic tutorial.](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html)

Comment: I have many plots, not sure how to generate widget object. Any help?